# Unable to close one frame on the click of a button

Tags: java, joptionpane

The click of the button should make the current form invisible but nothing happens.Can anyone help me with this

```
if(e.getSource = b5) {
    int r = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Exit", "Exit?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

    if(r == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
        encoder cc= new encoder() // this is the frame i am currently working in
        cc.setVisible(false);     // this should make the form invisible but that is not   happening
        cc.dispose();
    }
}
```

please help

Comment: Its not working.Nothing happens. The frame stays visible

Comment: Then i think that your condition didn't become a true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating new encoder and try to make it invisible and dispose right away.
This is never made visible, so making it invisible makes no sense to me.

Comment: Thanks i realized that. So since i am already working in the encoder so i am not creating an object of it instead i am writing this.setVisible(false) on the click of button but it still wont become invisible

Answer (score 0):

Your `e.getSource = b5` in the if statement needs to be `e.getSource == b5`. You're assigning, not evaluating.

Comment: yes it is that way. sorry i committed an error while typing.

Comment: Actually it should be `e.getSource() == b5` if `e` is the Event.